# Apache Ivy Config Standard

Tags: apache, svn, configuration, ivy

I'm trying to set up my first Ivy-powered build and am running into implementation problems, and I feel like I don't fully understand Ivy terminologies & best practices, even though I've spent a great deal of time reading the official docs and countless articles.

I have a SVN server that I want to use as the central repository for all of my projects. I do *not* want to use any public repositories! When I need a JAR, I'll pull it down from one of those public repos, run a checksum for security, and then push it to my SVN server (wherebyit will be deemed to be a "certified" version of the JAR; by certified, I really mean "safe").

(1) I want all of my projects to share the same **ivy-settings.xml** file. Do I put this in my SVN root, or somewhere inside SVN that makes sense? Here was my tentative thinking:

```
svn://MyRepoRoot/
    ivy/
        ivy-settings.xml
        artifacts/
    Project1/
        trunk/
            ivy.xml
            ...
        branches/
        tags/
    Project2/
        ...
    ...
```

The `ivy/` directory would contain a master copy of my `ivy-settings.xml` file. It would also contain an `artifacts` subdirectory where all of my "certified" JARs/WARs would go (as well as any publications my projects produce for downstream modules). **Can I request for commentary**?

(2) Also, something that I'm just not getting, is if each of my projects (modules) have their own `ivy.xml` file, and I want that file to reference the "global `ivy-settings.xml` file, which should by all means fall under its own, non-module-related versioning scheme, how do I pull down, say, `Project1`'s trunk as my working copy, but configure it with the settings file which is not even a part of the same SVN project?!?

Thanks to anyone who can help give me a little practical advice and better clarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ivysettings.xml is not referenced in the ivy.xml. You need the ivysettings.xml in your ant tasks to find the defined resolver, which resolve the artifacts defined in the ivy.xml.

ivy.xml defines the dependencies and ivysettings.xml the (local) runtime environment for ivy. You can change the ivysettings.xml anytime without need to edit the ivy.xml files.

The ivysettings.xml needs to be referenced in yout (ant) build.xml in ivys [`<settings />`](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/settings.html) task.

As for the layout. I use the same approach and it works fine for me. 
I wrote my antfiles, so that I need to have the ivy folder checked out parallel to my project(s).

Another approach could be [svns externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html). But I never tried that.

If your svn has access over http you could also use the url parameter of the  task to access ivysettings.xml.